# Passing a variable into a javascript function in PHP to make specific divs hide or show?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am trying to create a simple FAQ page where the user clicks the question and the answer appears below it (or hides it, if clicked again).

I got it working up to a point where all the questions will show the answer labeled "ans1". But I would like to pass a variable from each question into the function so it makes the associated answer appear. Question 1 will show Answer 1, Question 2 -> Answer 2, and so on.

My function...

```
function theAnswer() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ans1");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

PHP...

```
<?php 
$answer = 1;
foreach($faqArray as $faq) {
    ?>
    <div class='product_container'>
        <div class='product_cell'>
            <a onclick="theAnswer()" href='#'>
            <?php echo $faq[0];?> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="answer" id="ans<?php echo $answer;?>" style="display:none;">
        <p><?php echo $faq[1];?></p>
    </div>
<?php 
    $answer = $answer + 1;
} ?>
```

If I put a variable in the onclick="theAnswer()" that dictates the associated div, how can I get the function to perform the desired result?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Add `ans<?php echo $answer;?>` as parameter for your function. Then hide/show the an element by id

Comment: Please search "Accordion with HTML/Css Or Bootstrap", and Clearly state your usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code is run server-side and your Javascript code is run client-side. So the two codes cant interact with each other. I recommend hiding your element with CSS use something like this:

```
.hide{
 display : none
 }
```

and set your your div to hide like this

```
<div class='hide' id='answer-<?php echo $answer;?>'> .... </div>
```

and you would remove hide from your element's class list like this

```
  function theAnswer(num){
   answer = document.querySelector('#answer-' + num)
   answer.classList.remove('hide')
  }
```

in your php code youd have to put in the value

```
 .....
<a onclick="theAnswer('<?php echo $answer;?>')" href='#'>
 .....
```

Comment: So in this case, every question/answer pairing would have it's own separate function?

Comment: no you can load different content inside your divs with you php or js

Comment: I think this would work with one div that was used to display all the answers. But I am going to have a dedicated answer block under each question. So #answer1, #answer2, etc... This is where I am getting confused. How can I dictate to show #answer2, if I click on #question2? See image I added to original post for visual

Comment: there i edited it for you

Comment: "_So the two codes cant interact with each other._" That's not quite true. AJAX can be used to communicate client->server and PHP can be used to output variables in JS

Comment: `id='answer'` That's ok for _one_ div/answer, what about multiple?

Comment: ive edited it to fit your situation hopefully it works :D

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. The ('#ans' + num) was the structure that I couldn't get right.